# Unknown column error in procedure with if statement

Tags: mysql

When I call this stored procedure it shows error: unknown column...

```
BEGIN
  if (
  `LastRow.Transaction`=4 and `LastRow.Xre`>1)
  then
  SELECT
  sleep(2);
END if;
end
```

Please note that `sleep(2)` is just to demonstrate to do something if condition is true. What would be the proper way to accomplish a test based on value of a specific record? In the above example the table (actually a View) has only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: What would be the proper way to accomplish a test based on value of a specific record?

If you mean, based on values in columns stored in one row of a table... it seems like we would need a query that references the table that retrieve the values stored in the row. And then we can have those values available in the procedure.

As an example

```
BEGIN
   -- local procedure variables, specify appropriate datatypes
   DECLARE lr_transaction BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
   DECLARE lr_xre         BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;

   -- retrieve values from columns into local procedure variables
   SELECT `LastRow`.`Transaction` 
        , `LastRow`.`Xre`
     INTO lr_transaction
        , lr_xre
     FROM `LastRow`
    WHERE someconditions
    ORDER BY someexpressions
    LIMIT 1
   ;

   IF ( lr_transaction = 4 AND lr_xre > 1 ) THEN
      -- do something
   END IF;
END$$
```

---

That's an example of how we can retrieve a row from a table, and do some check. We could also do the check with SQL and just return a boolean

```
BEGIN
   -- local procedure variables, specify appropriate datatypes
   DECLARE lb_check TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

   -- retrieve values from columns into local procedure variables 
   SELECT IF(`LastRow`.`Transaction` = 4 AND `LastRow`.`Xre` > 1,1,0)
     INTO lb_check
     FROM `LastRow`
    WHERE someconditions 
    ORDER BY someexpressions
    LIMIT 1
   ;

   IF ( lb_check ) THEN
      -- do something
   END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: Thx, now I understand that the `if ... end if` code requires a variable that takes its value from a sql statement.